# Space Characters managment in Playfair cipher Algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm, cryptography

i'm trying to implement this algorithm; you can find a good description here

[LINK - Chapter 11.6 - Playfair Cipher](http://press.princeton.edu/chapters/s11_8214.pdf)

I'm getting some thoughts about the **decryptying phase**.

After i follow the instructions for crypting the text i get:

35VRX2NZDCR25885

then to decrypt i follow the instruction in the opposite direction, but i'm stucked at the point i get the message decrypted as follow

LETUSMEETATNOON

How could I pass from "LETUSMEETATNOON" to "LET US MEET AT NOON"?

Should I treat spaces in a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spaces are not allowed as a plaintext nor a ciphertext of your cryptosystem as it is defined in the attached document.

You could use a larger definition matrix and add all the useful symbols you need, probably `. , ; - ? ! : ' \ /` and maybe a newline.

---

There is one more approach. It is a general issue: How to add spaces to a text to get human readable (English) sentences? How to recognize a valid English sentence? This is a very hard problem of mathematical linguistics, which has not been solved yet.

In your case you could omit syntactical analysis and check the validity of words only. You could easily check all possible splits and check if all resulting words are valid English words. All you need is a good English dictionary (list of all English words), which can be found for example on Linux in folders `/usr/share/dict/` or `/var/lib/dict/` and many others can be downloaded from the Internet.

---

On Playfair algorithm:

Do not use it if you need any real security - it could be very easily broken using frequency analysis.

Comment: I'm just reading this. I really appreciated your answer. Yeah, I think using a larger matrix for spaces, points and comma is the simplest solution.

I think the other approach would be an interesting exercise.

I didn't wanted to use it in a real security case, it was just a school exercise.